# How do I determine if two numbers in a given range are significantly different

Tags: statistics, algorithms

Say I have a range of $[0...256]$, and I have a stream of data representing a change in an attribute, how do I determine if two points change by a significant amount, i.e. $[... 5,240 ...]$?

Is there an algorithm that works in this situation that I could use to see if the points are different in a significant way, based only on the two numbers and the range of values?

I plan to use this in image analysis to find boundaries between different colored pixels.

Comment: Subtraction? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat I mean in context, I want to tell if something is following a pattern or if it's a random deviation.

Answer (score 1):

What do you call significant?  You can certainly subtract them and divide by the range to see what fraction of the range they differ by.  Is differing by $10\%$ of the range (here $25$) significant?

Comment: That's part of my problem, if the difference across the range steadily increases, I don't want it to be marked as different, I want it to be different if there is a drastic, random change.

Comment: If I have $[1,3,7,10,15,21,100]$, I want the last element to stand out

Comment: There is no magic to it.  You need to look at a bunch of data and see what you think is significant.  Until you have some sort of model, you can't tell what is significant.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment.** @RossMillikan is correct that you need to develop a criterion
for significance. In your Comment on his answer you used the phrase "drastic, random change." *What might that mean?* Not having actual data at hand, I decided to do some
simulation.

***Long strings.*** Here are results of one experiment. I looked at strings of length $n = 100$
of digits randomly chosen from among $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, 256\},$ and looked
at the maximum absolute differences `max.dif` of *successive numbers* in each of a million such strings. The mean was about 233.5 with SD about 12.5; about 90% exceeded 216, and about 99% exceeded 199. To me, it seems clear
that a difference between successive values that exceeds 200 should always
be considered remarkable.

A histogram of these `max.dif`s is shown below.

[image]

***Short strings.*** To see how big a difference is remarkable for relatively short strings, I
repeated the simulation with $n=10.$
The mean was about 180.6 with SD about 37.7; about 90% exceeded 229, and about 99% exceeded 129. To me, it seems clear
that a difference between successive values in a string of 10 that exceeds 90 should always
be considered remarkable.

```
m = 10^6;  pop = 0:256;  n = 10;  max.dif = numeric(m)
  for(i in 1:m) {
  string=sample(pop, n, repl=T)
  max.dif[i] = max(abs(diff(string)))  }
mean(max.dif);  sd(max.dif)
## 180.5514
## 37.70648
quantile(max.dif, c(.01, .10, .90))
## 1% 10% 90% 
## 89 129 229
```

[image]

Perhaps these particular experiments are not useful, but at least they
are based on something approaching an *objective criterion.* Based
on your experience, you may be able to do simulations with results
that are more useful.

***Control charts***. An *entirely unrelated path of inquiry* is for you to look at the literature
on 'control charts', long used by quality engineers to detect when a
process is going 'out of control'. Several criteria are commonly
used as signals for trouble, some of which may be useful here.

***Change point in time series.*** (Added later.) Over lunch a colleague
suggested you might look in the literature of time series for criteria
to detect 'change points', usually detecting a point in time at which
the mean of the series appears to change.